# Permissions and discretionary access-control in Unix

Tags: unix, permissions, access-control

I have difficulties understanding on how to approach and solve the following:

> While inspecting the discretionary access-control arrangements on a
>   Unix computer, you find the following setup:
>
> Members of group staff:
>
> - Alex
> - Benn
> - Cloe
>
> Members of group gurus:
>
> - Cloe
>
> [permissions assignment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oSnLA.png)
>
> (The file `microedit` is a
>   copy of `/usr/bin/vim` program, which is a normal text editor)
>
> Task: Draw an access control matrix that shows for each of the above
>   five files, whether alex, benn, or cloe are able to obtain the right
>   to read or write its contents

I am heavily confused by this task.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please transcribe the information from the image into the question (it's 6 lines of output from `ls -ld` — it should be plain text indented as code in the question).  Verbatim copies of homework are often viewed as not showing enough research effort.  You should show what you've got so far, and ask about what you're confused about in context of your best effort.  If you still don't understand, you need to go back to your lecture notes or text book.

Comment: Basically, you need to create a table with file names down the left and three users across the top, and for each cell, whether the user can read the file or write the file or both.  You should have an explanation of why, too.  Note that `microedit` is a SUID program — and the permissions in general are intricate.

Comment: You might also note that the output is manufactured: the link counts on the two directories are wrong.  The number should be at least two for `src`; it should be at least 3 for `.`.